# How to find specific ID MS project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I would like to be able to find a specific UID in MS project file.
I found the below code but it is not working...I have found it macro online.

```
Sub FindUID()
    Dim T As Task
    Dim Temp_UID As Integer
    Dim UID As Integer
    Dim ID As Integer
    
    ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.Number10 = Application.ActiveSelection.Tasks.Item(1).UniqueID
    
    UID = InputBox("Enter UID", "UID")
    ID = 1
    
    ActiveProject.AutoFilter = True
    
    
    For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
        Temp_UID = T.UniqueID
        If Temp_UID = UID Then
            ID = T.ID
        End If
        Debug.Print T.UniqueID
    Next T
    
    If ID <> 1 Then
        SelectRow Row:=ID, RowRelative:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "UID Not Found", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If
    
    ActiveProject.AutoFilter = True
    OutlineShowAllTasks
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To jump to a task, use the [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.find) method. Find can be used with any field and various tests (e.g. equals, contains, etc). For example:

```
Sub GotoUID()

    ' make sure all tasks are shown
    SummaryTasksShow True
    FilterApply "All Tasks"
    SelectAll
    OutlineShowAllTasks
    SelectBeginning
    
    Dim UID As Integer
    UID = InputBox("Enter UID", "UID")
    
    Find "Unique ID", "equals", UID
    
End Sub
```